# Mule 4 spring bean in domain is not visible in the main app

Tags: spring-bean, mulesoft

Mule 4 spring bean in domain is not visible in the main app: defined dataSource bean in domain, then trying to access it in the main app using app.registry.dataSource. It is always null. When bean was defined in the main app, it worked. Is there any way to access this bean in the main app? I know that bean is created: if I provide incorrect parameters, I see errors in the domain log. This is only for Mule 4.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question seems to lack some information. We don't know how you're defining the bean or how you access it. Can you please post a [mre], or at least the relevant code in your app that's triggering the error?

Comment: Bean is defined in domain: spring.xml file (used Mule example, updated with the info relevant to Oracle data source), bean id is ubeDataSource. Added file name in mule-artifact.json to export, and spring-config in domain xml. In the app use app.registry.ubeDataSource and it is null. When the same config was defined in the application - this statement above returned valid data source object. When I set incorrect values in bean definition (wrong user id or password)  I see error in domain log, so assume that bean is created, but I do not know how to access it in the app.